# Explanation of "expr1 ? expr 2 : expr 3"?

Tags: c, operators

I'm having a hard time understanding this statement here:

```
for( int i=0; i< out_length; i++){

     int num=i < length_a ? array_a[i] : 0;

...
...
```

what I googled:

> expr1 ? expr2 : expr3
>
> If expr1 evaluates to a non-zero value, expr2 is evaluated, otherwise
> expr3 is evaluated. The value of the expression as a whole is which
> ever of expr2 or expr3 is evaluated (this means the type of expr2 and
> expr3 must be the same).

but I'm still confused, it will be helpful if you can turn that statement into some **if-else** blocks, thanks for the help..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

expr1 ? expr2 : expr3

Equivalent if else is:

```
if(expr1)
{
   //Evaluate expr2
}
else
{
   //Evaluate expr3
}
```

So your statement in the code evaluates as:

```
int num=i < length_a ? array_a[i] : 0;
```

means

```
if(i<length_a)
{
   num = array_a[i];
}
else
{
   num = 0;
}
```

Comment: The important difference is that the ternary operator is an expression, rather than a statement. So for example `func(x?1:10)` is valid syntax, whereas you could not do that with if statements (directly).

Comment: Yea thats true. I also clearly added that it *means* that and cannot always *replace* it.

Answer (score 4):

EXP1 ? exp2 : exp3

resolves to

```
if(exp1){  //if exp1==1
    exp2    //do this
  }
else{       //if exp2==0
    exp3    // do this
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int num=i < length_a ? array_a[i] : 0;
```

Equivalent to

```
int num;

if(i<length_a)
    num = array_a[i];
else
    num = 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

The expression

```
int num=i < length_a ? array_a[i] : 0;
```

is equivalent to

```
if(i < length_a)
    num = array_a[i];
else
    num = 0;
```

In other words, if the first part evaluates to true, the whole expression is equal to the second part; whereas, if the first part evaluates to false, the whole expression is equal to the third part.

This is a *ternary* operator, as opposed to a binary operator.

More information on the `?:` operator here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#C

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the code you're wondering about is the same as:

```
int num;
if (i < length_a) {
    num = array_a[i];
} else {
    num = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int num=i < length_a ? array_a[i] : 0;
```

This translates into

```
int num;

if (i < length_a)
{
  num = array_a[i];
}
else
{
  num = 0;
}
```

The first part is the conditional: `i < length_a`. If this evaluates to true, the second part is returned: `array_a[i]`. If the first part evaluates to false, the third and final part is returned: `0`.

Answer (score 0):

i hope your code is as follows

```
for( int i=0; i< out_length; i++){
 int num=i < length_a ? array_a[i] : 0;
}
```

and if you want in terms of if else... then here's the code.

```
 for( int i=0; i< out_length; i++)
{
   if(i<length_a)
  {
     int num = array_a[i];
  }
  else
  {
     int num = 0;
  }
}
```

i did code is so simple to make you understand the code easily, i hope this is what you are looking for.... and might help you to understand how to code in both the ways.

Comment: Not exactly, unless you intend to duplicate all code following the ternary operator.  You should move the declaration of `num` to before the `if` statement so that its value can be used after the `if` statement.

Comment: yes, i can do that and we can do lot of optimizations on the code like- removing '{' and '}' etc. but i converted given code literally in terms of if-else.... i did this way because i don't want to make code complex to read for a starter.

Answer (score 0):

int num = i < length_a ? array_a[i] : 0;

here the value of 'num' deals with the condition...i.e.,

when value of 'i' less than 'length_a' then, num=array_a[i]

otherwise, when 'i' greater than or equals to 'length_a' , num=0